# Not able to navigate on specific page on clicking notification sent by FCM

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, navigation, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification using spring boot and FCM service with following payload format:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "body": "this is a body",
    "title": "this is a title",
  },
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "sound": "default",
    "status": "done",
    "screen": "NotificationsPage",
  },
  "to": "<FCM TOKEN>"
}
```

notification sent succesfully with above payload but the issue is on flutter side.
i am not able to navigate to specific page after clicking on this notification.
My flutter code is as follow:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      dev.log("onMessageOpnedApp: ${message.data['screen']}");

      if (message.data["screen"] == "NotificationsPage") {
        dev.log("true");
        navigatorKey.currentState
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Dashboard()));
      }
    });
```

Almost tried many solution.please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()`

Comment: I had used that too, but dosn't worked for me. Could you give some example on that.

Comment: I had solved the problem by Firebase.onMessageOpenedApp() method.